# How to convert number into percentage

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a pyspark data frame, Do you know how to convert numbers with decimals into percentage format? I can even determine the number of decimal points I want to keep.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ```python
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
columns = ['id', 'row', 'rate']
vals = [('A', 1, 0.01)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
```
I want to convert the last column into 1%.

Answer (score 5):

You can multiply with `100`

```
df.withColumn("rate",(col("rate") * 100).cast("int")).show()
+---+---+----+
| id|row|rate|
+---+---+----+
|  A|  1|   1|
+---+---+----+
```

---

```
df.withColumn("rate",concat((col("rate") * 100).cast("int"),lit('%'))).show()
+---+---+----+
| id|row|rate|
+---+---+----+
|  A|  1|  1%|
+---+---+----+
```

Comment: I know. But I want to format into percentage with % sign so that when using display function from Databricks notebook, it would show %.

Comment: For that case we need to do concat with `%` for rate column